# CreatePopup replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

Using regular JavaScript or JQuery I want to replace the createPopup() method like done in this post:

[A universal createPopup() replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807709/a-universal-createpopup-replacement)

but I want to use a Div instead of an iFrame. I don't need anything fancy just a simple div which can be styled.

The problem with using a Div is that I have a lot of existing code like this which I would like to remain untouched e.g.

```
var popup = window.createPopup();
oPopup.document.body.innerHTML = "Click outside <strong>popup</strong> to close.";
```

In the new `createPopup()` method below, is there a way to return an object that has the properties `document.body.innerHTML` to style the Div and the existing code can remain untouched.

```
if(!window.createPopup){
  window.createPopup = function() {

    // TODO return div object

    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want to mimic some of what an iframe would do (have certain properties like `document.body.innerHTML`), but don't want to use an iframe right?

Comment: You can easily create a function that will return an object that has the same properties, but I'm guessing the createPopup method immediately presents the popup to the user?  Adding something to `oPopup.document.body.innerHTML' would automatically update the existing shown dialog?  Seems like the automatic update of the content would be hard, I think only the latest versions of ECMA script allow "watchers" on properties.  Not sure without researching though.

Comment: You should try replacing that linked createPopup() replacement with a Div, what didn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript setters and getters in combination with `defineProperties` to pull off what you are trying to do.

```js
if(!window.createPopup){
  window.createPopup = (function() {
    // build our object
    var o = {
      document: {
        body: {
          _innerHTML: ''
        }
      }
    };

    // build the popup
    o.document.body._outer = document.createElement('div');
    o.document.body._inner = document.createElement('div');
    o.document.body._outer.className = 'modal';
    o.document.body._inner.className = 'inner';
    // attach popup
    o.document.body._outer.appendChild(o.document.body._inner);
    document.body.appendChild(o.document.body._outer);

    // add a property for innerHTML
    Object.defineProperties(o.document.body, {
      'innerHTML': {
        get: function () { return this._innerHTML; },
        set: function (x) { 
          this._innerHTML = x;
          this._inner.innerHTML = this._innerHTML;
        }
      }
    });

    // return the object
    return o;
  });
}

var oPopup = window.createPopup();
oPopup.document.body.innerHTML = "Click outside <strong>popup</strong> to close.";
```

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.modal .inner {
  padding: 2em;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank You Joseph, this is exactly what I needed and very well done. Thanks a million!